# Text after <br> dissapears after replacing br tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping some data from websites and have encountered a problem using `BeautifulSoup` (`bs4`). I need to get text of some elements, separated by anything (comma, space, etc.) that enables me to split the text in order it appears.

`text` attribute of `bs4.element.Tag` gives textual content. The problem is, I am getting the text concatenated, even if there is a `<br>` in between. I have no way of differentiating whether `OneTwo` is one word/sentence or multiple.

I am using `find_all` to find all `<br>` tags and I replace them with comma `,` so I can split the text by it. However, replacing `br` tags seems to remove text that follows the `br` tags.

Here is some code that reproduces the problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            One
            <br>
            Two
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
""".replace(' ', '').replace('\n', ''), "html.parser")

print soup.div.text
# Out: OneTwo

for br in soup.find_all('br'):
    br.replace_with(',')

print soup.text.replace('\n', '')
# Out: One,
```

What I want it to print is `One,Two` or `One,Two,,` or something similar instead. How can I replace the `br` tags with a character, without removing other text in the process?

Comment: You can try ``divText = [word for word in soup.div.split('<br>') if word]``

Comment: As stated, this still doesn't separate the individual words. I cannot know if One is a single word or not.

Comment: Edited, please look again.

Comment: Remember, `soup` is not a usual string. It doesn't have a `split` method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there probably are many ways to do this, but I wanted a clean solution that will work for real-world, possibly horrible html.

If someone comes looking for solution to similar problem, I stumbled upon one neat method, `insert`, which is exactly what I was looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            One
            <br>
            Two
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
""".replace(' ', '').replace('\n', ''), "html.parser")

for br in soup.find_all('br'):
    br.insert(0, ',')

print soup.text.replace('\n', '')
# Out: One,Two,,
```

---

**Edit**

Even better solution that Padraic Cunningham suggested is to just concatenate the text of `br` to the replacement, which will retain the original text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup("""
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            One
            <br>
            Two
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
""".replace(' ', '').replace('\n', ''), "html.parser")

for br in soup.find_all('br'):
    br.replace_with(',' + br.text)

print soup.text.replace('\n', '')
# Out: One,Two
```

Comment: `br.replace_with(","+br.text)`

Comment: Oh, nice. Post that as answer and I will accept it. Never thought `br.text` would contain actual text..

Comment: You can edit it into your own answer if you want, not sure why your answer was downvoted.

Comment: Some people think that [answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467) is bad practice, I guess.